# Deleting comments

Tags: discussion, comments, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we clean up obsolete comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/should-we-clean-up-obsolete-comments)

Sometimes a comment discussion appears under a question or answer. This quite often ends in some edit that covers the comments. Is it good or bad? Is it just tolerated or really welcomed? Should one clean the comment area this way often?

(I usually add a comment like: *I think that couple of previous comments can be deleted.* Then I delete my previous comments and after the second person deletes his, I finally delete this last comment.)

Answer (score 10):

Comments are in general intended to 'add value' to a question or answer. Often, they are used to obtain clarification or to point to a potential improvement to an answer. If this occurs, the comments are then no longer needed. As the StackExchange approach is not a 'discussion forum', comments which have ceased to be 'useful' can reasonably be removed.

Comment: I think that this is covered somewhere in the FAQ or on meta.SO, but can't of course find the appropriate link :-)